# Inserting records into a MySQL table using Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, insert-into

I created a database with one table in MySQL:

```
CREATE DATABASE iac_enrollment_system;

USE iac_enrollment_system;

CREATE TABLE course(
    course_code CHAR(7),
    course_desc VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    course_chair VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY(course_code)
);
```

I tried to insert a record using Java:

```
// STEP 1: Import required packages
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

public class SQLInsert {
// JDBC driver name and database URL
static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/iac_enrollment_system";

// Database credentials
static final String USER = "root";
static final String PASS = "1234";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    String course_code = null, course_desc = null, course_chair = null;

    try {
        // STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        // STEP 3: Open a connection
        System.out.print("\nConnecting to database...");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
        System.out.println(" SUCCESS!\n");

        // STEP 4: Ask for user input
        System.out.print("Enter course code: ");
        course_code = scn.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter course description: ");
        course_desc = scn.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter course chair: ");
        course_chair = scn.nextLine();

        // STEP 5: Excute query
        System.out.print("\nInserting records into table...");
        stmt = conn.createStatement();

        String sql = "INSERT INTO course " +
            "VALUES (course_code, course_desc, course_chair)";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

        System.out.println(" SUCCESS!\n");

    } catch(SQLException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if(stmt != null)
                conn.close();
        } catch(SQLException se) {
        }
        try {
            if(conn != null)
                conn.close();
        } catch(SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Thank you for your patronage!");
  }
}
```

The output appears to return successfully:
[image: insert_success]

But when I select from MySQL, the inserted record is blank:
[image: mysql_blank_record]

Why is it inserting a blank record?

Comment: You are not using course_*** variables in query.

Comment: You aren't setting any values on the insert statement. Check out using a preparedStatement with bind variables rather than making up a "string" insert statement.  This will insert the data and will stop you getting SQL injection issues.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

no that cannot work(not with real data):

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO course " +
        "VALUES (course_code, course_desc, course_chair)";
    stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

change it to:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO course (course_code, course_desc, course_chair)" +
        "VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
```

Create a  PreparedStatment with that sql and insert the values with index:

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
preparedStatement.setString(1, "Test");
preparedStatement.setString(2, "Test2");
preparedStatement.setString(3, "Test3");
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Hi, I tried changing the part of the code into [this](http://pastebin.com/ZCrxG6F3). But it is returning `cannot find symbol` for variable `prepareStatement`.

Comment: of couse you have to create it before using.

Comment: PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

Comment: Hi, sorry if I am new to this. I have changed the code. [Here](http://pastebin.com/WNyxcbqQ) is my pastebin. It is throwing a `Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery()`.

Answer (score 3):

this can also be done like this if you don't want to use prepared statements.

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO course(course_code,course_desc,course_chair)"+"VALUES('"+course_code+"','"+course_desc+"','"+course_chair+"');"
```

Why it didnt insert value is because you were not providing values, but you were providing names of variables that you have used.

Comment: You should always use preparedStatements.  This type of code is bad practice and will lead to SQL injection issues.

Comment: Aayush, I disagree.  You shouldn't learn bad habits as they will stick.  Learn to use preparedStatements from the beginning and you will write better code.

Comment: I am not asking to learn this thing and use it, I mentioned it because its a feature and one should know about this plus this solves his answer too.

Comment: I personally don't use this anymore, I use ORM framework like hibernate.

Comment: I have opted to use the PreparedStatement approach. Still, your explanation on why it didn't insert values was helpful. Upvote for that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for any table, instead of hard-coding the columns.

```html
//Source details
    String sourceUrl = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//server:1521/db";
    String sourceUserName = "src";
    String sourcePassword = "***";

    // Destination details
    String destinationUserName = "dest";
    String destinationPassword = "***";
    String destinationUrl = "jdbc:mysql://server:3306/db";

    Connection srcConnection = getSourceConnection(sourceUrl, sourceUserName, sourcePassword);
    Connection destConnection = getDestinationConnection(destinationUrl, destinationUserName, destinationPassword);

    PreparedStatement sourceStatement = srcConnection.prepareStatement("SELECT *  FROM src_table ");
    ResultSet rs = sourceStatement.executeQuery();
    rs.setFetchSize(1000); // not needed


    ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();



    List<String> columns = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= meta.getColumnCount(); i++)
        columns.add(meta.getColumnName(i));

    try (PreparedStatement destStatement = destConnection.prepareStatement(
            "INSERT INTO dest_table ("
                    + columns.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", "))
                    + ") VALUES ("
                    + columns.stream().map(c -> "?").collect(Collectors.joining(", "))
                    + ")"
            )
    )
    {
        int count = 0;
        while (rs.next()) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= meta.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                destStatement.setObject(i, rs.getObject(i));
            }
            
            destStatement.addBatch();
            count++;
        }
        destStatement.executeBatch(); // you will see all the rows in dest once this statement is executed
        System.out.println("done " + count);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in your insert statement chage it to below and try :
 `String sql = "insert into table_name values ('" + Col1 +"','" + Col2 + "','" + Col3 + "')";`

Comment: While this also solves the problem, I have opted to use the PreparedStatement approach. Thank you for your help.